# Woocommerce can't disable Guest Checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and am having problems disabling the guest checkout.

I have made sure **'Enable Guest Checkout'** is **unticked** in the settings page but people are still able to checkout without creating an account or logging in.

Is there somewhere else I should be setting this?

Comment: Is the "Anyone can register" option unticked in the Settings -> General tab?

Answer (score 3):

Go to WooCommerce > Accounts and untick Enable registration on the "Checkout" page.

This should do the job!

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, you can add this code to your theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_restirct_checkout' );
function woo_restirct_checkout() {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() ) {

        $my_account_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );
        wp_redirect( $my_account_url );
        exit;

    }
}
```

Cheers,
Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Also need to **unticked** the option from **Woocommerce -> Accounts** tab.
Where it says **Enable registration on the "Checkout" page**.

Comment: Can't believe it was this simple!

Answer (score -1):

Try looking at the site in a different browser from the one you're developing on. I found that being logged in as a user in wordpress-admin, also made me an active, logged in user for the checkout.